# Building an Array in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am trying to build an array in localstorage based on a product view history on an ecommerce site. Every time a user views a product page I want to add the ID of this page into the array in local storage.

```
var itemArray = [];
    var myItem = $("li#ref").data("ref");
    itemArray.push(myItem);
    var LS = {
        set: function (key, val) {
            return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        }
    };
    LS.set("Viewed", itemArray);
```

The problem I have is it never builds an array the latest product I look at just overides the one before so I only ever get one entry.

Do you know if this is possible to achieve?

thanks in advance

Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append new value to existing array stored in local storage, not new empty array:

```
var LS = {
    set: function (key, val) {
        return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
    },
    get: function (key) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    }
};

var itemArray = LS.get('Viewed') || [];
var myItem = $("li#ref").data("ref");

if (itemArray.indexOf(myItem) !== -1) {
    itemArray.push(myItem);
}

LS.set("Viewed", itemArray);
```

You should probably also check if the value is already in array to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thanks very much as simple as that :D

Comment: And also add check if LS.get('Viewed') returns object that is not array (or insert empty array on some initialize state) because first time when you call LS.get('Viewed') it will return null.

Comment: Thanks to you both for this, the issue I have now is I never get into itemArray.push(myItem); as in the first instance item array is always [] if that makes sense.